# Duplicate usernames in bounty tooltip

Tags: bug, bounty

I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23728051) when I realized that [Unihedron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622940/unihedron)'s name was mentioned twice in the tooltip, given that they awarded two bounties to that same answer.

[image: "This answer has been awarded bounties worth 150 reputation by Unihedron and Unihedron"]

To me that sounds like as if two people sharing the same name have individually awarded at least one bounty each. Shouldn't it be something like:

> This answer has been awarded bounties worth 150 reputation by Unihedron

...or:

> This answer has been awarded bounties worth 150 reputation by Unihedron (2 times)

Comment: [Reported on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284403/bounty-tooltip-shows-same-name-multiple-times) a while ago.

Comment: Thanks. From now on I will search MSE before MSO since that seems to be a wiser choice.

Comment: Depends, there are quite a few SO-specific things, which fit here better. But generally MSE is indeed more "broad" in its context and variety of bugs, yes.

Comment: As for this specific bug, it's actually useful to know a user gave more than one bounty, so better give this info in a better way, e.g. "Unihedron (100, 50)" which also say amount of each bounty.